# Eliminating partially overlapping parts of 2 vectors in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, stringr

I wonder if it might be possible to drop the parts in `n1` character vector that ***partially overlap*** with elements in `f1` formula.

For example, in `n1`, we see `"study_typecompare"` & `"study_typecontrol"` partially overlap with `study_type` in `f1`.

Thus in the `desired_output`, we want to drop the `"study_type"` part of them. Because other elements (ex. `time_wk_whn`) in `n1` fully overlap with an element in `f1`, we leave them unchanged.

Is obtaining my `desired_output` possible in BASE `R` or tidyvesrse?

```
f1 <- gi ~ 0 + study_type + time_wk_whn + time_wk_btw + items_whn + 
  items_btw + training_hr_whn + training_hr_btw

n1 <- c("study_typecompare","study_typecontrol","time_wk_whn",      
        "time_wk_btw","items_whn","items_btw","training_hr_whn",
        "training_hr_btw") 

desired_output <- c("compare","control", "time_wk_whn",      
                    "time_wk_btw","items_whn","items_btw",        
                    "training_hr_whn","training_hr_btw")
```

Comment: Is your question about updating the formula or getting a vector as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a function to pass the formula and the vector ('fmla', 'vec') respectively.  Extract the variables from the 'fmla' (`all.vars`), find the values in the vector that are not found in the formula variables (`setdiff`), create a pattern by `paste` those variables and replace with blank (`""`) using `sub`, and update the 'vec', return the updated vector

```
fun1 <- function(fmla, vec) {

    v1 <- all.vars(fmla)
    v2 <- setdiff(vec, v1)
    v3 <- sub(paste(v1, collapse = "|"), "", v2)
    vec[vec %in% v2] <- v3
    vec

}
```

-checking

```
> identical(fun1(f1, n1), desired_output)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @SimonHarmel The reason is that some of the arguments have functions ` all.vars(f2)
[1] "gi"   "v_gi"` that is not the case in your example.  Can you post as a new question

Comment: Hi Arun, In the following example, it looks like your above solution doesn't work, is there a fix? `f1 <- yi ~ bmi * ch ;
n1 <- c("intrcpt", "bmi", "chyes", "bmi:chyes");
fun1(fm1, nm1)`

Comment: @SimonHarmel Please post as a new question.  My solution is based on the example you provided.  You are coming up with new examples that are not the case in the examples

Comment: @SimonHarmel I don't know your expected output when your formula have `bmi` and the `n1` have `bmi:chyes`.  Please post as a new question

Comment: Please post as a new question as the pattern is different

Comment: @SimonHarmel in your example, the `f1` already have `bmi`.  So, why you are not removing the 'bmi' in the 'n1'

Comment: @SimonHarmel But you are changing the chyes to yes whereas not removing the bmi

Comment: @SimonHarmel sorry, that is a different question as it doesn't follow the pattern you showed in the example and I didn't understand why one is removed whereas other is not

Comment: In case, a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70707278/16762740) of interest.