# Followup: Eliminating partially overlapping parts of 2 vectors in R

Tags: r, string, character, stringr

I'm following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467618/16762740). I wonder if it might be possible to drop the parts in `n1` character vector that ***partially overlap*** with elements in `f1` formula.

For example, in `n1`, we see `"timePost-test 1"`&`"timePost-test 2"` partially overlap with `time` in `f1`.

Thus in the `desired_output`, we want to drop the `"time"` part of them. Because other elements in `n1` fully overlap with an element in `f1` (ex. `time_wk_whn`), we leave them unchanged.

I have tried the following solution, but can't get my `desired output` (below).

Is obtaining my `desired_output` possible in BASE `R` or tidyvesrse?

```
foo <- function(fmla, vec) {
  
  v1 <- all.vars(fmla)
  v2 <- setdiff(vec, v1)
  v1 <- paste0('^', v1)
  v3 <- sub(paste(v1, collapse = "|"), "", v2)
  vec[vec %in% v2] <- v3
  vec 
}

f1 <- gi ~ 0 + time:pub_type + time_wk_whn + time_wk_btw

n1 <- c("time_wk_whn","time_wk_btw",
        "timePost-test 1:pub_typejournal","timePost-test 2:pub_typejournal")
#================================ EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(f1, n1)

# [1] "time_wk_whn"                 "time_wk_btw"                
# [3] "Post-test 1:pub_typejournal" "Post-test 2:pub_typejournal"

desired_output <- c("time_wk_whn","time_wk_btw",
                          "Post-test 1:journal","Post-test 2:journal")

#== Similarly `f1` and `n1` can contain non-charctor elements (below) but 
#== the desired output should remain the same.

f1 <- gi ~ 0 + factor(time):pub_type + time_wk_whn + time_wk_btw  

n1 <- c("time_wk_whn","time_wk_btw", "factor(time)Post-test 1:pub_typejournal",
                                     "factor(time)Post-test 2:pub_typejournal")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea works but just needs a bit more preprocessing. Consider

```
foo <- function(fmla, vec) {
  v1 <- as.character(attr(terms(fmla), "variables"))[-1L] # Get the terms instead of the variables. This gives you `factor(time)` but not `time`.
  v2 <- setdiff(vec, v1)
  v1 <- gsub("([\\\\^$.?*|+()[\\]{}])", "\\\\\\1", v1, perl = TRUE) # Escape all special characters
  v3 <- gsub(paste(v1, collapse = "|"), "", v2)
  vec[vec %in% v2] <- v3
  vec 
}
```

Output

```
> foo(
+   gi ~ 0 + factor(time):pub_type + time_wk_whn + time_wk_btw, 
+   c("time_wk_whn","time_wk_btw", "factor(time)Post-test 1:pub_typejournal", "factor(time)Post-test 2:pub_typejournal")
+ )
[1] "time_wk_whn"         "time_wk_btw"         "Post-test 1:journal" "Post-test 2:journal"
> foo(
+   gi ~ 0 + time:pub_type + time_wk_whn + time_wk_btw, 
+   c("time_wk_whn","time_wk_btw", "timePost-test 1:pub_typejournal", "timePost-test 2:pub_typejournal")
+ )
[1] "time_wk_whn"         "time_wk_btw"         "Post-test 1:journal" "Post-test 2:journal"
```

Comment: I think in line 4 of your code (`v1 <- gsub(r"(([\^$.?*|+()[{]))", r"(\\\1)", v1)`), there is bug, right?

Comment: Where is the bug? Have you tried running this function? @SimonHarmel

Comment: Rstudio thinks, `r` used in `r"(([\^$.?*|+()[{]))"` and `r"(\\\1)"` is an anomoly?

Comment: I think either you are using an outdated Rstudio or an outdated R.  `r"(...)"` is the syntax introduced in R 4.0.0 to represent string literals. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html). If that does not work for you, we can always escape everything by hand. I have updated the code. @SimonHarmel

Answer (score 0):

When you append the `^`, you are stating that it needs to be the start of the string. Additionally, `sub()` will only look for the first match. You will need to use `gsub()`.

```
foo <- function(fmla, vec) {
  v1 <- all.vars(fmla)
  v2 <- setdiff(vec, v1)
  v3 <- gsub(paste(v1, collapse = "|"), "", v2)
  vec[vec %in% v2] <- v3
  vec 
}

fmla <- f1 <- gi ~ 0 + time:pub_type + time_wk_whn + time_wk_btw

vec <- n1 <- c("time_wk_whn","time_wk_btw",
        "timePost-test 1:pub_typejournal","timePost-test 2:pub_typejournal")

desired_output <- c("time_wk_whn","time_wk_btw",
                    "Post-test 1:journal","Post-test 2:journal")
x = foo(f1, n1)
# [1] "time_wk_whn"         "time_wk_btw"         "Post-test 1:journal"
# [4] "Post-test 2:journal" 
all.equal(desired_output, x)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, Kat! But I use `"^"`, because sometimes `f1` and `n1` can also be: `f1 <- gi ~ 0 + factor(time):pub_type + time_wk_whn + time_wk_btw ;

n1 <- c("time_wk_whn","time_wk_btw", "factor(time)Post-test 1:pub_typejournal","factor(time)Post-test 2:pub_typejournal")`. Now if you try your solution, you'll see you get: `[1] "time_wk_whn"   "time_wk_btw"                
[3] "factor()Post-test 1:journal" "factor()Post-test 2:journal"`. In this case, the desired output is same as above.