# Add NA from one square matrix and place it in another square matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix

I was wondering if it might be possible to pick the `NA` columns and `NA` rows from the `d1` square matrix and place them into `d2` square matrix to achieve my `DESIRED`, `d3` square matrix?

This is a toy example, and `d1` and `d2` square matrices can be of any dimension. Thus a function to achieve similar `NA` replacements is appreciated.

```
m1="
a1 a2     a3   a4   a5   a6  a7  a8   a9     b1   b2     b3
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.1    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.3  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.1    NA   0.0    NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.3    NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA"

d1 <- sapply(read.table(text=m1,h=T),as.numeric)


m2="
a1 a2     a3   a4   a5   a6 a8   a9   b2
1  2.0    1    9    4    0  0.0  3.0  1.0
0  0.1    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0  0.0    7    0    0    0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0  0.0    0    5    0    0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0  0.0    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0  0.0    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0  0.0    0    0    3    0  0.3  0.0  0.0
0  0.0    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.1  0.0
0  0.0    8    0    6    0  0.0  0.0  0.6"

d2 <- as.matrix(read.table(text=m2,h=T))

DESIRED="
a1 a2     a3   a4   a5   a6  a7  a8   a9     b1   b2     b3
1  2.0    1    9    0    0   NA  0.0  3.0    NA   1.0    NA
0  0.1    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    7    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    5    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
0  0.0    0    0    3    0   NA  0.3  0.0    NA   0.0    NA
0  0.0    0    0    0    0   NA  0.0  0.1    NA   0.0    NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
0  0.0    8    0    6    0   NA  0.0  0.0    NA   0.6    NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA"

d3 <- as.matrix(read.table(text=DESIRED,h=T))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `d1` has the correct size, copy `d1` to `d3` and then copy the elements of `d2` into the non-NA elements of `d3`:

```
d3 <- d1
d3[!is.na(d3)] <- d2
# or a one-liner
d4 <- replace(d1, !is.na(d1), d2)
identical(d3, d4)
#> [1] TRUE
d3
#>       a1  a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7  a8  a9 b1  b2 b3
#>  [1,]  1 2.0  1  9  4  0 NA 0.0 3.0 NA 1.0 NA
#>  [2,]  0 0.1  0  0  0  0 NA 0.0 0.0 NA 0.0 NA
#>  [3,]  0 0.0  7  0  0  0 NA 0.0 0.0 NA 0.0 NA
#>  [4,]  0 0.0  0  5  0  0 NA 0.0 0.0 NA 0.0 NA
#>  [5,]  0 0.0  0  0  0  0 NA 0.0 0.0 NA 0.0 NA
#>  [6,]  0 0.0  0  0  0  0 NA 0.0 0.0 NA 0.0 NA
#>  [7,] NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA
#>  [8,]  0 0.0  0  0  3  0 NA 0.3 0.0 NA 0.0 NA
#>  [9,]  0 0.0  0  0  0  0 NA 0.0 0.1 NA 0.0 NA
#> [10,] NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA
#> [11,]  0 0.0  8  0  6  0 NA 0.0 0.0 NA 0.6 NA
#> [12,] NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA
```

Note: it appears that the first element of the "desired" matrix that you posted should be `1` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use logical subsetting, find the NAs from matrix 1 and subset in matrix 2.

```
> x <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
> y <- x
> 
> x[1,2] <- NA
> x[2,3] <- NA
> x[3,5] <- NA
> 
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0   NA    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0   NA    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0   NA
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
> y
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
> 
> y[is.na(x)] <- NA
> y
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0   NA    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0   NA    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0   NA
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```